# java.lang.NullPointerException when i try to persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jsf-2

I'm coding an application in mave,jsf ,spring ,jpa/hibernate , when I try to access a "user" jsp page mapped to the " UserManagedBean" I get an exception:

```
GRAVE: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:775)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1267)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.java.projet.managed.bean.UserManagedBean.addUser(UserManagedBean.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:98)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 20 more
24 oct. 2013 19:54:48 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
ATTENTION: #{userMB.addUser}: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{userMB.addUser}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:775)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1267)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.java.projet.managed.bean.UserManagedBean.addUser(UserManagedBean.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:98)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 20 more
24 oct. 2013 19:54:48 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet Faces Servlet a généré une exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.java.projet.managed.bean.UserManagedBean.addUser(UserManagedBean.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:98)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:775)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1267)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Here the code of my UserManagedBean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userMB")
@RequestScoped
public class UserManagedBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String ERROR = "error";

    // Spring User Service is injected...
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{UserService}")
    private IUserService userService;

    List<User> userList;

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    /**
     * Add User
     * 
     * @return String - Response Message
     */
    public String addUser() {
        try {
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(getId());
            user.setName(getName());
            user.setSurname(getSurname());
            userService.addUser(user);
            return SUCCESS;
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ERROR;
    }

    /**
     * Reset Fields
     * 
     */
    public void reset() {
        this.setId(0);
        this.setName("");
        this.setSurname("");
    }

    /**
     * Get User List
     * 
     * @return List - User List
     */
    public List<User> getUserList() {
        userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        userList.addAll(getUserService().getUsers());
        return userList;
    }

    /**
     * Get User Service
     * 
     * @return IUserService - User Service
     */
    public IUserService getUserService() {
        return userService;
    }

    /**
     * Set User Service
     * 
     * @param IUserService
     *            - User Service
     */
    public void setUserService(IUserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    /**
     * Set User List
     * 
     * @param List
     *            - User List
     */
    public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    /**
     * Get User Id
     * 
     * @return int - User Id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Set User Id
     * 
     * @param int - User Id
     */
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Get User Name
     * 
     * @return String - User Name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Set User Name
     * 
     * @param String
     *            - User Name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Get User Surname
     * 
     * @return String - User Surname
     */
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    /**
     * Set User Surname
     * 
     * @param String
     *            - User Surname
     */
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

}
```

UserDAO.java

```
public class UserDAO implements IUserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void addUser(User user) {
        this.em.persist(user);
    }

    public void updateUser(User user) {
        this.em.merge(user);

    }

    public void deleteUser(User user) {

        this.em.remove(user);
    }

    public User getUserById(int id) {

        // List list = em.createQuery("from User where id=?").setParameter(0,
        // id)).list();
        User instance = em.find(User.class, id);
        return instance;

    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        try {
            // process query
            Query query = em.createQuery("select u from User u ");
            List<User> results = (List<User>) query.getResultList();
            // log.trace("find all not deleted users successful");
            return results;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            // log.error("find all not deleted users failed", re);
            return new ArrayList<User>();
        }
    }

}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(int id, String name, String surname) {

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "NAME", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "SURNAME", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public String getSurname() {
        return this.surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

}
```

UserService.java

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserService implements IUserService  {

   IUserDAO userDAO;


    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void addUser(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         getUserDAO().addUser(user);

    }

     @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void updateUser(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         getUserDAO().deleteUser(user);

    }

     @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void deleteUser(User user) {
         getUserDAO().updateUser(user);

    }

    public User getUserById(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return  getUserDAO().getUserById(id);
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return  getUserDAO().getUsers();
    }

    public IUserDAO getUserDAO() {
        return userDAO;
    }

    public void setUserDAO(IUserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }


}
```

db.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to 
        configure as beans -->
    <bean id="placeholderConfig"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:db.properties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="${db.dialect}" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Use this definition if using a Java EE 6 container This also stops Eclipse 
    from complaining that 3.0 is not a valid version <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"> -->
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/app/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/spring/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Welcome Page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/pages/index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Comment: Ok. Where you creating the instance of `IUserDAO` when you injected in `Service` class? My strong guess that's cuasing the null pointer

Comment: you have to add spring jsf resolver in faces xml file

Answer (score 0):

From the UserManagedBean.java:

```
public String addUser() {
    try {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(getId());
        user.setName(getName());
        user.setSurname(getSurname());
        userService.addUser(user);
        return SUCCESS;
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ERROR;
}
```

Can you verify that the userService instance in this method is not null?
Did you debug the method? Maybe the injection of the bean does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

id, name and surname are not initialised in userManagedBean.
When you call addUser, you create a new user. Then you try to set the variables with the variables from userManagedBean, which are again not initialised.

Answer (score 0):

Your Spring bean (UserService) is not injected into your JSF managed bean (UserManagedBean). Check the followings:

1. SpringBeanFacesELResolver has to be configured in your faces-config.xml
2. an instance of the UserService class (with the name of "UserService"!) has to exist in your Spring context by either:

   - manually declaring it in your application-context.xml
   - or marking it with @Service annotation and using component scan